# How to convert base64 encoded image to image and set it as an Image resource for an image button in android studio

Tags: java, android, image, base64, android-resources

I am building an android app. I have a Base64 encoded string. I need two answers:
 - How to convert encoded string to image
 - How to set it as image resource for an image button

Comment: That is one part of question. but I can set image resource to image button which are in drawable folder. how to set this base64 decoded image  as image esource which is not in drawable folder.

Comment: convert base64 into bitmap and set the bitmap to image view or image button

Answer (score 0):

```
String base="****Base64 string values of some image******”;
byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(base.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
ImageButton image = (ImageButton )this.findViewById(R.id.imagebutton);
image.setImageBitmap(
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length)
);
```